# Keycloak error in quarkus: [org.key.ada.aut.PolicyEnforcer] Could not lazy load resource with path

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I'm working on quarkus 3.3.2, using a keycloak bearer token to connect to some apis. Here's my configuration:

```
# keycloak
# OIDC Configuration
%prod.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://keycloak....
%test.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://keycloak....
%dev.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://keycloak....
quarkus.oidc.client-id=my-client
%prod.quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=...
%test.quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=...
%dev.quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=...
quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=required
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
```

In order to use AuthzClient, the property quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable is set to true:

```
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
```

This works so far, but the quarkus application itself also supplies some public resources (like health check etc.), which should not be protected by keycloak. But by requesting these resources, I always get errors like this:

```
2023-09-25 16:31:02,956 ERROR [org.key.ada.aut.PolicyEnforcer] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) Could not lazy load resource with path [/css/enunciate.css] from server: org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthorizationDeniedException: org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 403 / Forbidden / Response from server: {"error":"invalid_clientId","error_description":"Client application [my-client] is not registered as a resource server."}
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.Throwables.handleAndWrapHttpResponseException(Throwables.java:96)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.Throwables.handleWrapException(Throwables.java:42)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.Throwables.retryAndWrapExceptionIfNecessary(Throwables.java:87)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.find(ProtectedResource.java:233)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.findByMatchingUri(ProtectedResource.java:292)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.PathConfigMatcher.matches(PathConfigMatcher.java:81)
    ...
Caused by: org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 403 / Forbidden / Response from server: {"error":"invalid_clientId","error_description":"Client application [my-client] is not registered as a resource server."}
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:103)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethodResponse$3.execute(HttpMethodResponse.java:68)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource$5.call(ProtectedResource.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource$5.call(ProtectedResource.java:223)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.find(ProtectedResource.java:231)
    ... 19 more
```

This is, what I mainly tried to omit these errors, following the advice on https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authorize-web-endpoints-reference.

```
quarkus.http.auth.permission.public.paths=/,/css/enunciate.css,/favicon.ico
quarkus.http.auth.permission.public.policy=permit
quarkus.http.auth.permission.public.methods=GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,OPTION,PATCH
```

But it doesn't have any impact.

I then tried it with explicitly enforcing the resource which needs authentication:

```
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.1.path=/tlnv-restservice/api,/tlnv-restservice/api/*
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.1.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING
```

This led to:

```
2023-09-25 16:37:31,775 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile [dev]): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    ... 
Caused by: org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 403 / Forbidden / Response from server: {"error":"invalid_clientId","error_description":"Client application [my-client] is not registered as a resource server."}
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:103)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethodResponse$3.execute(HttpMethodResponse.java:68)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource$5.call(ProtectedResource.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource$5.call(ProtectedResource.java:223)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.find(ProtectedResource.java:231)
    ... 23 more
```

It seems, as if the keycloak policy enforcer regards every resource as a client resource to be enforced.
So how can I exclude them to be considered as resources of the keycloak client and to be lazy loaded by the keycloak policy enforcer?

Comment: I solved the problem by a workaround:

Comment: Solved the problem by removing quarkus-oidc- and quarkus-keycloak-authorization-dependencies from the project and replacing the org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient by a plain java.net.http.HttpRequest, doing the oicd access token request.
I'm not sure, wether the unwanted behaviour described above is a bug in quarkus 3.3.2 which might be fixed in future versions.